# Evaluate success data from jQuery .ajax() and return true/false based on result

Tags: ajax, jquery

Greetings stackoverflow community. I am a long time lurker, and first time poster. I've spent several hours doing research trying to overcome the below problem, obviously without success as I am posting here. It should be noted that I have only been coding with jQuery(or any JS for that matter) for a couple of months.

My goal is this: Submit a simple form with .ajax(), and then either alert(Success!) and return true (reload the page) if the returned success data == 'Success', or populate a div with an error message and return false otherwise.

I have tried many different approaches that I found during my research, but no matter what I've tried I can get an evaluation of the success: data to return true.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#error').hide();

    $("#submit_result").submit(function() { 
        var postString = $('#submit_result').formSerialize(); /* Function from jQuery.form.js */
        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/submit_speedtest.inc.php', 
            type:'POST',
            data:postString,
            success: function(msg) {
                $('#error').html(msg);
            },
            error:function() {
                $('#error').html('Error validating CLid!');
            }
        });
        if ($('#error').html() == 'Success') {
            alert('Done');
            return true;
        }
        $('#error').show();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Everything works great, except:

```
if ($('#error').html() == 'Success') {
alert('Done');
return true;
}
```

This test never evaluates to true. I've tried it many different ways, including things like

```
if $("#error:contains('Success')") {
```

Contents of submit_speedtest.inc.php:

```
    <?php

session_start();

include('lib.inc.php');
restrict_unauthorized();

if(!empty( $_POST['clid'])) {
    $clid = trim($_POST['clid']);
    $result = check_clid($clid);
    echo $result;
}else{
    echo "No CLid!";
}

?>
```

The check_clid() function runs a simple MySQL query to make sure CLid exists. As stated, this seems to work fine

I hope this all makes sense, and I very much appreciate any help the stackoverflow community can offer me.

**Edit**

Thank you both for your input. I was able to glean useful information from both your responses. You gave me a better understanding of how the callbacks worked.

Here is the jQuery code I ended up with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#status_msg').hide();

    $("#submit_result").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var postString = $('#submit_result').formSerialize(); 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'inc/submit_speedtest.inc.php', 
            type:'POST',
            data:postString,
            success:function(msg) {
                $('#status_msg').html(msg);
                $('#status_msg').show();
            },
            error:function() {
                $('#status_msg').html('<font color="red">Error validating CLid!</font>');
                $('#status_msg').show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP does the rest of the work, and it all works fine.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

$ajax is async and for that reason you must not return anything, you should organize your code in a different way.

```
  $("#submit_result").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var postString = $('#submit_result').formSerialize(); 
   $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/submit_speedtest.inc.php', 
        type:'POST',
        data:postString,
        success: function(msg) {
            $('#error').html(msg);
            alert('Done');
            $('#error').show();
            //do whatyou need to do after you have succesfully vompleted the ajax request
        },
        error:function() {
            $('#error').html('Error validating CLid!');
            $('#error').show();
        }
    });

});
```

in your code

```
  if $("#error:contains('Success')")
```

will always be false because it's executed immediately after the ajax function is called, without waiting for the function to complete. You could set the `async` property to `false` in the `$.ajax()` call to make the call synchronous, but that defies the utilities of ajax

Answer (score 0):

You success and error callbacks are not run until after your submit has already completed.

What you should do it just return false in the submit callback and then do the rest of your logic in the appropriate callbacks from your ajax request:

```
$("#submit_result").submit(function() { 
    var postString = $('#submit_result').formSerialize(); /* Function from jQuery.form.js */
    $.ajax({
        url: 'inc/submit_speedtest.inc.php', 
        type:'POST',
        data:postString,
        success: function(msg) {
            // call submit directly on the form
            $("#submit_result")[0].submit(); 
        },
        error:function() {
            // display error message
            $('#error').html('Error validating CLid!').show();
        }
    });
    // return false to stop the submit
    return false;
});
```